# Prepared statement on MySQLDatabase object

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to the object oriented way of coding and I have the following problem. I've written my code without prepared statements at first, but want to implement them now. The code worked flawlessly without the prepared statements.

self::$tablename is the name of the table.

self::instantiate returns an array of attributes of that table.

```
public static function find_by_id($id = 0) {
    global $database;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . self::$tablename . " WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"; 
    $param = "i";
    $var = $id;
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql, $param, $var);
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}

public static function find_by_sql($sql="", $param, $var) {
    global $database;
    $stmt = $database->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($param, $var);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result_set);
    $object_array = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch($result_set)) {
        $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $object_array;
}
```

I've included my database object as

```
$database = new MySQLDatabase();
```

which print_r($database) gives:

```
MySQLDatabase Object ( [_connection:private] => mysqli Object ( ) [last_query] => )
```

and

```
$this->_connection = mysqli::__construct(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

My first problem is how to access this mysqli object.

PHP.NET gives the following explanation of the mysqli object

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

If I write that instead of $database it works. It fails at $stmt->bind_param() however.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
PHP gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MySQLDatabase::prepare()
```

Comment: $database it's not an instance. It's a null/empty variable at `$database->prepare($sql)` and must have your DSN setup

Comment: But the print_r($database) shows that there is a mysqli Object in MySQLDatabase Object right? Which is the object I need to access right? Because new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world") is the same as that mysqli Object?

Comment: After all why you are using a super global var `global $database`? You can use `function __construct() {  $this->db = new mysqli(...) }` and use `$this->db->prepare()` at your methods and avoid poison that var

Comment: Should I write that construct function in every class? And doing so returns the `error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: You can extends your db class, ie, `class Foo extends Database { ... }` and only inside your methods you can use `$this` - this is OO basic rules. and use `$f = new Foo; $f->db->prepare('...'); // outside class scope` - or you can use traits at newer versions of php to implement the same.

Comment: Seems like I'm getting there. Getting the error: `mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement` now

Comment: You can implement a public method as `public function db() { return $this->db; }` and $db will be a private var after all.

Comment: Thanks, this works. The only problem now is that I'm running on PHP version 5.2.17 and get_result is not available for me. For re-usability I can't write every database field in my get_result(). I cannot upgrade the version just yet, so I'll have to do with mysqli_real_escape string etc.